# Is it possible to use single XSLT 1.0 file for different ASP.NET pages?

Tags: asp.net, xslt-1.0

I've tried to find on internet clear answer to the question if it's possible to use single XSLT 1.0 file for different ASP.NET pages, but didn't find it.

I'm not sure how this should work. Do we have to use parameters and some kind of sections in XSLT file?

The example would be more than welcome.

Comment: do you use the xslt for a XMlDatasource?

Comment: XSLT is used for XML data from Xml web control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use same xslt for multiple pages setting **Xml.TransformSource** by code behind

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xml.transformsource%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The TransformSource property is used to specify the path to an XSL
>   Transformation style sheet file (representing an XSL Transformation
>   style sheet) used to format the XML document before it is written to
>   the output stream. You can use a relative or an absolute path. A
>   relative path relates the location of the file to the location of the
>   Web Forms page or user control, without specifying a complete path on
>   the server. The path is relative to the location of the Web page. This
>   makes it easier to move the entire site to another directory on the
>   server without updating the path to the file in code. An absolute path
>   provides the complete path, so moving the site to another directory
>   requires updating the code.

It's possible to define source and transform file by code behind:

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/day7x985%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
         XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
         doc.Load(Server.MapPath("people.xml"));

         XslTransform trans = new XslTransform();
         trans.Load(Server.MapPath("peopletable.xsl"));

         xml1.Document = doc;
         xml1.Transform = trans;
      }
```

**EDIT**

I don't understand very well what do you mean with:

> I need something that could tell me where to go inside the file.

but if you need some arguments in your transformation, you could use [TransformArgumentList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.transformargumentlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
xslArg.AddParam("date", "", d.ToString());
xml1.TransformArgumentList = xslArg;
```

Comment: The TransformSource property refers to the XSLT file, but I need something that could tell me where to go inside the file.

Comment: @tesicg I don't understand very well what do you mean with something that could tell me where to go inside the file, anyway just edited